# Removing object of NSMutableArray returns exception after row deleting

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsrangeexception

Here is my problem :

I have an `NSMutableArray *notes` and which the source of my `UITableView* _gradesTV`.

I added the method `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` here :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        NSLog(@"%ld", (long)indexPath.section);
        NSLog(@"%@", notes);




        [_gradesTV beginUpdates];

        [notes removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

        [_gradesTV deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section]
                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

        [_gradesTV endUpdates];




        NSLog(@"%@", notes);
    }

[_gradesTV reloadData];

}
```

But when i delete an element I get this error :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException',
 reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'
```

But the NSLog I make on the MutableArray show me 3 elements ...

The line `removeObjectAtIndex` on the notes (MutableArray) makes my app crash like it was executed twice ...

Thank you for your help ...

[Github Link](https://github.com/rico237/MyGrades/tree/DeleteRow_UItableView)

if u want to pull the project and try ...

You will have to create grades with the + button then you can try to delete an item on my table view.

When adding a grade the first TextField is a `string`, the second one is a `double` value, the third one is also a `double` value.

Comment: Isn't `indexPath.section` should be `indexPath.row`

Comment: Can you please post all your `UITableView delegate` methods.

Comment: You can pull all the project at this address if you want, all answers provided don't work for now ... [Github Link of the project](https://github.com/rico237/MyGrades/tree/DeleteRow_UItableView)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with following code..

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSections {
    return [notes count];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        NSLog(@"%ld", (long)indexPath.section);
        NSLog(@"%@", notes);
        [notes removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        NSLog(@"%@", notes);
    }

[_gradesTV reloadData];

}
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer made me realize I wasn't using the right MutableArray (notes) to get the number of sections :/

Comment: Welcome wolber..

You got solution that is more important.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly** remove `UITableView's` `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates`

**Secondly** remove `UITableView's` `reloadData` as no need when using  `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete` and `UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert`

Now your code will be :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        NSLog(@"Current Section : %ld", (long)indexPath.section);
        NSLog(@"Before : %@", notes);

        [notes removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

        // Either delete some rows within a section (leaving at least one) or the entire section.
        id sectionDataSource = [notes objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        if ([sectionDataSource count] > 0)
        {
            // Section is not yet empty, so delete only the current row.
            [_gradesTV deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
        else
        {
            // Section is now completely empty, so delete the entire section.
            [_gradesTV deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section] 
                     withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }

        NSLog(@"After : %@", notes);
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO I think major problem is at `indexPath.section`. OP is referring to section and not row...

Comment: I already tryed this code i found on stackoverflow but it didn't solve my problem, i changed the question and included a github link with the whole project if u wanna try

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are deleting section instead of row.

`[notes removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section];` should be `[notes removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Also `[_gradesTV deleteSections` should be `[_gradesTV deleteRow...`

***Note:*** *You should use `[_gradesTV deleteRow...` or `[_gradesTV reloadData];` because both are useless. I would say just use `[_gradesTV deleteRow...`*

Also not sure `beginUpdates` & `endUpdates` are for what. Remove the un-necessary stuff.

Comment: My project work more with sections than rows and if i use `indexPath.row` i won't delete the right item ... I changed the question to include the Github link of the project if you want to try with all files

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured from where came my mistake,  it was just that I didn't used the same MutableArray to get the number of sections ...

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return [notes count];
}
```

The old method had an old NSMutableArray I was using to test my code ...

Thank you all even if I was just too noob to notice it by myself ....